# Registration-Free COM in ASP WebPage

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, dll, com, regfreecom

I have a Webpage application which uses in the code behind DLL's and OCX's, some of these DLLs  are VB6 ones and the others are C++. At the moment the access to these DLL's / OCX's is through the registy, i would like to change this using [RegFree COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx).

Problem: All examples i have found until now are demonstrating how to modify an EXE which accesses DLL to Registry Free one using the manifest files, assuming we have one EXE and one DLL the Registration Free access would produce one manifest file for the EXE (in which the dependency to the DLL's mnaifest is set) and another one for the DLL (which references the DLL), in my case i dont have an EXE but a Browser, so i am stuck with the EXE's manifest.

Is it possible to use Registry Free COM in my scenario? if yes where do i set the dependency between EXE->DLL, is it in somewhere Visual Studio??

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might look at http://www.mazecomputer.com/sxs/help/iis6config.htm which describes the process required.

If you truly mean ASP.Net try http://www.mazecomputer.com/sxs/help/iis6aspnet2.htm